# Recognize undefined Entities in Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, entities, watson-conversation

Please, I wanted to know if it is possible to catch different entities on Watson conversation without defining their values. 
For example, I am working on a Mobile up for room booking in my company and I can't define all the room's names so I want that my Bot recognize the name just according to the used pattern for example 
"Book @room for tomorrow"
and whatever I put in place of @room it takes it as a room name.

thank you

Comment: this name is a number?

Comment: You can use regex for this. Watson Conversation supports SPEL

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi No it is not

Comment: @Dudi Is that valid even for words within phrases ? Or I have to do it in the Script

Comment: You can do it in the dialog tool. More details on dialog methods here https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/dialog-methods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its now available check out https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#pattern-entities

A pattern must be entered as a regular expression in the field.
For instance `internationalPhone: ^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$, e.g., +44 1962 815000`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The solution below still works but right now the pattern entities as discussed by Dudi are more systematic solution. Leaving this here for legacy reasons.

---

Right now the regexp support inside Watson Conversation Service is probably the est bet.

For your particular example, you can use the following expression inside the dialog node condition:

`input.text.matches('^[bB]ook[^\w]+(\w+).+ (tomorrow|today)$')`

and inside that node you can add the following regexp to node `context` to extract the second word (or the word after "Book") to a variable:

`"room" : "<? input.text.extract('^[bB]ook[^\\w]+(\\w+).+ (tomorrow|today)$',1) ?>"` 
(note that in `context` unlike in conditions you need to actually escape `\` with another `\`)

This will match inputs such as "book bathroom for today" or "book r101 for tomorrow".

A good place where you can try your regexp expressions is https://regex101.com/

Comment: The problem is that my rooms can sometimes have a composed named like Room Pablo Picasso,

Comment: You can extend the regexp by listing all the special room names instead of using \w+, however, then it might get bigger... E.g. ^[bB]ook[^\w]+(Pablo Picasso|\w+).+ (tomorrow|today)$ Alternatively you can match for more words before "for tomorrow" String.

Comment: mm if I have to list all the rooms names that means that it would be better for me to add them into entities. Think that it's one of the cons of Conversation