# Using Watson conversation, how to handle customer, account number etc

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson, watson-dialog

I'm creating sample application using Watson conversation API in nodejs. I'm trying to get username and send them to Watson and then I want to say hello "$username", also I want to keep that throughout the conversation so that I can if the user ask if I remember the name, Watson can say "yes, "$username"".

Can someone help me with sample code, how to use intent in this use case.

```
    // Start conversation with Hello message.
conversation.message({
  input: { text: "Hello" },
    }, processResponse);

// Process the conversation response.
function processResponse(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); // something went wrong
    return;
  }

  // If an intent was detected, log it out to the console.
  if (response.intents.length > 0) {
    //console.log('Detected intent: #' + response.intents[0].intent);
    console.log(response.context)
  }

  // Display the output from dialog, if any.
  if (response.output.text.length != 0) {
      console.log("Watson : "+response.output.text[0]);
  }

  // Prompt for the next round of input.
    var newMessageFromUser = prompt('Me : ');
    // Send back the context to maintain state.
    conversation.message({
      input: { text: newMessageFromUser },
      context : response.context,
    }, processResponse)
}
```

Comment: This name is set with code? Or you request the name inside conversation and you can use they after?

Comment: Watson will ask the name to the user. And I want to handle it with proper intent and store it in the context and use it throughout the conversation. customer would just enter just name or "my name is Ashok".... Not sure how to handle them in intent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use context variables for that.

To extract the name, request the name in `1º node`, and in the `next` node, add this JSON:

```
{
  "context": {
    "name": "<? input.text ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Hello $name."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

The `input.text` capture all user has typed.

You can use `$` for set and get the context variable with the name: `$name` will show what user has typed.

In other case, if user typed my name is XXXXX, you can use regex inside your context variable. Check this example for use REGEX inside context variables:

```
   "name" : "<? input.text.extract('^[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]+$') ?>"
```

@MichelBida did one example with regex, but with another request for user, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187182/recognize-undefined-entities-in-watson-conversation/43210612#43210612).

**EDIT:**

Use:

`context.myproperty = "Hello World";`

And now have the System Entity `@sys-person`, this entity extracts names from the user's input. Names are not normalized by the system, so "Will" is not treated as "William", nor vice versa, see [official](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-person) documentation. This entity can be active within `Entity -> System Entities -> @sys-person`

Comment: [see that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041442/watson-responds-with-one-api-code)