# WATSON conversation to fetch real time data from Rest API

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

We are creating a Bot using Watson, which will provide the rate of food materials to the end user and along with the availability. In order to fetch the availability, we need to call a rest API with the food details, which in turn will provide us the status.

So, here I wanted to know, how we can call rest api from Watson to fetch (feed) data into conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use Watson Conversation, and create the Intents with responses based on the food materials.

You'll use the `Context variable` to get the food when use types and your application code will do something with this value. In this case, providing the status.

You can create one **entity** with all food values, and get the value with `context` variable with:

```
{
  "context": {
    "foodValue": "<? @foodtype ?>"
  },
```

Inside your app, debug the return, you'll see one array if user types more than 1 food value.
And, with this values you'll check and return something for the user, I cant show any example because you does not specify what language you're use.

How to use context variable: click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229538/using-watson-conversation-how-to-handle-customer-account-number-etc/43232835#43232835).

See the official for call the API [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/).

See the official documentation about [Conversation Service](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/index.html).

Check one project with [Weather](https://github.com/doconnor78/conversation-simple-weather) example from IBM Developer, this project gets the City from user typed and with this data do something in the app, in this case, return the Weather.